# hibernate with ehcache not working well

Tags: spring, hibernate, ehcache

I'm using Spring 4, Hibernate 4 for my project.
Recently, I added ehcache into the project. There is an entity com.xxx.Employee which holds another entity com.xxx.User. I used HibernateTemplate findByCriteria(DetachedCriteria, int, int) to execute query, and then, make another query via HibernateTemplate get(entityName, id), there is no SQL shown in the logging, this seems that the second cache works, however, the User of Employee is missing, there is "org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session" thrown.

Is there additional setting need add for save Object's Object value to the cache?

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.xxx">
<class name="Employee" table="t_employee">
    <cache usage="read-write" include="all"/>
    <id name="personId" column="person_id">
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>

    <property name="name" column="name" />

    <many-to-one name="department" column="department_id" fetch="join" not-null="false" />
    <many-to-one name="user" column="user_id" fetch="join" not-null="false" cascade="all-delete-orphan" unique="true"/>

</class>
```

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.xxx">
<class name="User" table="t_user">
    <cache usage="read-write"/>
    <id name="userId" column="user_id">
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="name" column="name" not-null="true" />
    <property name="loginName" column="login_name" unique="true" not-null="true" />
    <property name="password" column="password" not-null="true"  />
    <many-to-one name="employee" column="employee_id" fetch="join" not-null="false" />
    <many-to-one name="role" class="Role" column="role_id" fetch="join" not-null="true" />
    <property name="lock" column="col_lock" type="integer" />
    <property name="createDate" column="create_date" />
    <property name="updateDate" column="update_date" />
    <property name="passwordUpdateDate" column="pwd_update_date" />
    <property name="loginTimes" column="login_times" type="integer" />
    <property name="lastLoginDate" column="last_login_date" />
    <property name="comment" column="comment" />

</class>
```

```
public T getOneById(Serializable id) throws TamsException {
    if (id == null) {
        logger.error("getOneById id is null");
        throw new TamsException("getOneById id is null");
    }
    T t;
    try {
        log.info("get " + getEntityName() + " by ID : " + id);

        HibernateTemplate ht = getHibernateTemplate();
        ht.setCacheQueries(true);
        t = (T) ht.get(getEntityName(), id);
        return t;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new TamsException("get " + getEntityName() + ":  failure!", e);
    } finally {
        log.info("get " + getEntityName() + " by ID : " + id + " success!");
    }
}


public List<T> queryByCondition(QueryCondition condition)
        throws TamsException {

    log.info("query " + getEntityName() + " by: " + condition + " ...");
    try {
        int firstResult = 0;
        int maxResults = 0;

        DetachedCriteria c = DetachedCriteria
                .forEntityName(getEntityName());

        if (condition != null) {
            firstResult = condition.getFirstResult();
            maxResults = condition.getMaxResults();
            assembleCriteria(condition, c);
        }
        HibernateTemplate ht = getHibernateTemplate();
        ht.setCacheQueries(true);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<T> list = (List<T>) ht.findByCriteria(c, firstResult,
                maxResults);

        log.info("query " + getEntityName() + " by: " + condition
                + " ret size --> " + list.size());
        return list;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new TamsException("query " + getEntityName() + " by: "
                + condition + " failure!", e);
    }

}
```

Comment: Finally, I use Spring Cache instead of Hibernate secondary level cache.

Answer (score 0):

You receive `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session` error, because property `Employee.user` is configured with option `lazy=proxy` (this is default, when not mentioned).

Here is [piece from documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#d5e3688):

> lazy (optional - defaults to proxy): by default, single point
>   associations are proxied. lazy="no-proxy" specifies that the property
>   should be fetched lazily when the instance variable is first accessed.
>   This requires build-time bytecode instrumentation. lazy="false"
>   specifies that the association will always be eagerly fetched.

So, now you've got 2 choices:

1. Use `lazy=false` to eagerly fetch the association
2. Open `Session` before working with required associations

Comment: If I don't use the cache, the code works well, so I think the problem is that when Hibernate get object from cache, it miss something.